# How to make MATLAB detect keyboard stroke (arrows) and record the data?

Tags: matlab, keyboard, keystroke

I am trying to make MATLAB code which detect left and right arrow keys of keyboard while there is a figure and record the key strokes.

```
double(get(gcf,'currentcharacter'))
```

I tried above function but I don't think it is the one I looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ginput

```
[~,~,button]=ginput(1);
switch button
    case 30 %up
    case 31 %down
    case 28 %left
    case 29 %right
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but how can I make 'crosshair' invisible? Before using it there isn't crosshair but it appears now.

Comment: You can edit ginput.m. In my matlab (2016b) it's line 260:
set(crossHair, 'Visible', 'on');
if you change that to
set(crossHair, 'Visible', 'off');
the crossHair is gone.

also if you comment out line 210
set(gcf,'Pointer','custom','PointerShapeCData',cdata,'PointerShapeHotSpot',hotspot)
the pointer stays visible.

Comment: The solution below by mendi barrel is more elegant. You write your own function for what should happen upon a keypress. But adapting ginput and renaming it to myginput.m is simpel.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Then if I modify ginput.m and send my file to someone else, then is it still applied?

Comment: No, because ginput.m is a matlab function. Someone else has the original function in their matlab. It is advisable to save it not as ginput.m but for example as "myginput.m" and refer to it in your program: [~,~,button]=myginput(1);
When you send it to someone you include myginput.m

Answer (score 0):

Something i wrote in the past for interactive zoom and pan in figures:

```
set(gcf,'WindowKeyPressFcn',{@KeyPressd,mean(xlim)});
```

And in 'KeyPressd.m':

```
  function [  ] = KeyPressd( src,evnt,S0 )
    switch evnt.Key
        case 'f'
            set(gca,'XLim', xlim + range(xlim)/100 );
        case 'v'
            set(gca,'XLim', xlim - range(xlim)/100 );
        case 'h'
            set(gca,'YLim', ylim + range(ylim)/100 );
        case 'n'
            set(gca,'YLim', ylim - range(ylim)/100 );
        case 'g'
            set(gca,'ZLim', zlim + range(zlim)/100 );
        case 'b'
            set(gca,'ZLim', zlim - range(zlim)/100 );

        case 'd'
            set(gca,'XLim', xlim - 0.02*(xlim-sum(xlim)/2) );
        case 'c'
            set(gca,'XLim', xlim + 0.02*(xlim-sum(xlim)/2) );
        case 'a'
            set(gca,'YLim', ylim - 0.02*(ylim-sum(ylim)/2) );
        case 'z'
            set(gca,'YLim', ylim +  0.02*(ylim-sum(ylim)/2)  );
        case 's'
            set(gca,'ZLim', 0.98*(zlim) );
        case 'x'
            set(gca,'ZLim', 1/0.98*(zlim) );

    end
    set(gca,'ZTickLabel',sprintf('%1.0f\n',get(gca,'ZTick')));
```